# Double UIScrollView synchronization - Different height

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview

I'm currently developping iPad application with 2 `UIScrollView` in the same page.
On the left side, there is the content and on the right side, there are some bloc, news. These two `UIScrollView` are different height size.

Example : left 1000, right 2000.

I would like to synchronize the 2 `UIScrollView`, I explain me :

When the user scrolls on the left `UIScrollView` to access on the bottom, the right `UIScrollView` "scrolls" in the same time. If the left UIScrollView is happened to be at the bottom, and the right `UIScrollView` is NOT on the bottom, the right `UIScrollView` continue to scroll until ... it stop naturally.
And the same behavior if the user scroll on the right UIScrollView.

Do you have an idea how to resolve or to handle my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to listen to the `delegate` method of `scrollViewDidScroll` then you can set the `contentOffset` of the second `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Yes I know but it generate some conflict : if i scroll the left, it call this function and the right call this function too, and so the left / right / left / right... generate bad behavior

Comment: add tags to the UIScrollViews and test about the tags in the delegate. If you find the left tagged you have to scroll the right tagged. You know what i mean here?

Answer (score 2):

I'll just post the solution I used in case anyone gets to this question in the future.

You don't set the `contentOffset` directly. You need to do a workaround. Like so:

```
CGRect viewToUpdateBounds = viewToUpdate.bounds;
viewToUpdateBounds.origin = scrolledView.contentOffset;
viewToUpdate.bounds = viewToUpdateBounds;
```

Regards